# Escaping a character in Javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping

Not sure if Im doing this correct. I have already tried adding the slashes. maybe im adding them in the wrong places?

```
+"<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='javascript:checkIn('"+ JsonParseData[i].businessID + "');'>Check in</button><br>"+
```

Comment: Don't program this way. The DOM is not a huge string to be constructed by concatenation.  You will pull out your hair. Use a templating library, or framework with templates, or DOM APIs, to manage the DOM.

Comment: I know this is kind of late but can you recommend one. @torazaburo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you are doing wrong

```
onclick='javascript:checkIn('"+ JsonParseData[i].businessID + "');'>
```

Change it to

```
onclick='javascript:checkIn(\""+ JsonParseData[i].businessID + "\");'>
```

Answer (score 1):

escape `"` using `\`

```
"<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='checkIn(\"" + "Testing" + "\");'>Check in</button><br>";
```

```js
var str = 'abc';

function checkIn(str){ console.log(str); }


str += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='checkIn(\"" + "Testing" + "\");'>Check in</button><br>";                                           
console.log(str);

document.body.innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: Thats what im getting too.

Comment: @Carlitos pls check now

Answer (score 1):

Your rendered HTML is using single-quotes around the attributes, so the JS needs to be in double-quotes:

```
+"<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='javascript:checkIn(\""+ JsonParseData[i].businessID + "\");'>Check in</button><br>"+
```

```js
x = '' +"<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='javascript:checkIn(\""+ 'xyz' + "\");'>Check in</button><br>"+ ''

document.body.innerHTML = x
```